# Send cURL request from Proxy IP - PHP

Tags: php, curl

Google most of time block my server IP whenever I try to fetch it.
Like we are make one Bulk Google PR checker script, google will block our IP after nearly 3k or 5k requests. So, just to give our Users best results, we need to send cURL request through some proxy.
Not only google, but we need it sometime to send requests through some proxy. So, if any body know then please tell the process, else shut your mouth to ask this off-topic.
How can I send cURL request from a proxy, not from my server IP? OR tell me better way to scrape google data ?

What is legal way to use cURL ?

Comment: "my IP" then "not from my server IP" please be more specific, you are talking about multiple things (which i personally don't know what are you asking, or what ip is it blocking)

Comment: when i send curl query, it sends my server IP and google block it.
I need to send curl query from any proxy ip, so google could block that proxy ip, not my server ip.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you should not do that

Comment: those who can, do; those who can't, scrape the sites of those who can

Comment: @Dagon - Even if Google scraped me first?

Comment: its not just to scrap google, but it was an example. many sites block our IP due to fetching their content with cURL. so to avoid being blocked, we should use Proxy IP to send cURL request.

Comment: -1 for `else shut your mouth to ask this off-topic`. If you're being blocked it's probably because _you shouldn't be doing what you're doing_ or are trying to make money by breaking the terms of service of freely accessible services.

Comment: @pguardiario you can ask google not to crawl your site, and it it wont. The question asker is not showing the same respect.

Comment: I was new to stackoverflow, it was my first question. I had a very bad attitude of people here. I think people here are just to answer the questions if they know, not to comment if we should do this or not. idiots don't know how to treat someone.

Comment: @AbidAli maybe edit your question so that it doesn't appear so rude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the option   `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);`

```
 //scape.php

class Scraper {

public function scrape($target_url) {
    $this->target_url = $target_url;

    $ch = curl_init();
    $proxy = $this->_getProxy();
    $userAgent = $this->_getUserAgent();
    if ($proxy) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
     }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if (!$html) {
        echo 'url/curl error';
        return false;
    }

    $this->html = $html;
    $this->_ParseData();
}



public function setProxy($proxy) {
    $this->proxy = $proxy;
}

private function _getProxy() {
    if (isset($this->proxy))
        return $this->proxy;
    else
        return false;
}

public function setUserAgent($agent) {
    $this->agent = $agent;
}

private function _getUserAgent() {
    if (isset($this->agent))
        return $this->agent;
    else
        return false;
}

 //Parsing data
private function _parseData() {

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($this->html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    // your xpath query here
    $elements = $xpath->query("//div[@id='ires']");

}

}
```

Example usage

```
require 'scrape.php';
$scraper=new Scraper;
$scraper->setProxy('127.0.0.1:9150');
$data=$scraper->scrape('https://www.google.com/#q=stack+overflow');
```

Comment: The question is  "Send cURL request from Proxy IP" What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: not all questions should be answered

Comment: Other than spelling proxy `proxie`, I don't have a problem with it.